# richface drop down selection

Tags: richfaces, drop-down-menu

I have a long list of items display on my drop down list.  So is that possible to limit the number of items in richface drop down selection list?  Preferable pagination will be enable.

Thanks

Comment: try to ask this in the richfaces forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you could use the autocomplete component

See here an example http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete